# How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Tough to explain so here's an example:

```
$strings = array(
   array("languageCode" => "ES",  "string" => "hola"),
   array("languageCode" => "EN",  "string" => "hello"),
   array("languageCode" => "IT",  "string" => "ciao"),
   array("languageCode" => "CHS", "string" => "您好"),
);
```

I would like to sort strings by `languageCode` value, by defining the order:

```
function magicStringOrder(array $strings, array $languageCodeOrder){
    // ....
    return $strings;
}

$strings = magicStringOrder($strings, array('EN', 'IT') );

$strings = array(
   array("languageCode" => "EN",  "string" => "hello"),
   array("languageCode" => "IT",  "string" => "ciao"),
   array("languageCode" => "ES",  "string" => "hola"),
   array("languageCode" => "CHS", "string" => "您好"),
);
```

There is `magicStringOrder`?

I now know that it is a simple problem to solve with a few loops. I would need a very fast function (it is called many times, with large array)

Comment: What is your expectation for values that don't have an entry in your languagecodeorder?

Comment: @MarkBaker if the order defined assume the position, otherwise maintain its position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea without php sort functions:

```
// sort by cmp $arr[$magic_key] <-> arr $magic_order
function magicSort($arr, $magic_key="", $magic_order = array())
{
  $sorted = array();
  foreach($magic_order AS $v) {
    foreach($arr AS $k2 => $v2) {
      if($v===$v2[$magic_key]) {
        $sorted[] = $v2;
        unset($arr[$k2]);
      }
    }
  }

  // attach what's left
  return array_merge($sorted, $arr);
}
```

[Test it at eval.in](https://eval.in/280700) (*link expires soon*)

```
$strings = array(
   array("languageCode" => "ES",  "string" => "hola"),
   array("languageCode" => "EN",  "string" => "hello"),
   array("languageCode" => "IT",  "string" => "ciao"),
   array("languageCode" => "CHS", "string" => "??"),
);

print_r(magicSort($strings, "languageCode", array("EN", "IT")));
```

*outputs to*:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [languageCode] => EN
            [string] => hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [languageCode] => IT
            [string] => ciao
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [languageCode] => ES
            [string] => hola
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [languageCode] => CHS
            [string] => 您好
        )

)
```

`$magic_order` can also be empty. If so, the array is just reindexed. Arrays with values, that don't exist in `$magic_order` are shifted down and order of those is maintained.

Not sure, if that's exactly what you need.

Comment: It works pretty simple, glad you like it @SimoneNigro :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a problem to give a weight to a language, the sorting becomes much easier and therefore quicker.

You can use `asort` to sort the array based on the `$languageCodeOrder` stored weights. If a language it's not present in the `$languageCodeOrder` its weight becomes 0 and goes towards the end of the ordered array.

The final order of the array will be from high weight to low. That is: if EN has a weight of 1 it will appear in the array after IT that has 2.

```
$strings = array(
    array("languageCode" => "ES", "string" => "hola"),
    array("languageCode" => "EN", "string" => "hello"),
    array("languageCode" => "IT", "string" => "ciao"),
    array("languageCode" => "CHS", "string" => "您好"),
);

function magicStringOrder(array $strings, array $languageCodeOrder) {
    uasort($strings, function($a,$b) use ($languageCodeOrder) {
        $val_a = (isset($languageCodeOrder[$a["languageCode"]])) ? $languageCodeOrder[$a["languageCode"]] : 0;
        $val_b = (isset($languageCodeOrder[$b["languageCode"]])) ? $languageCodeOrder[$b["languageCode"]] : 0;

        return $val_b - $val_a;
    });
    return $strings;
}

$strings_ordered = magicStringOrder($strings, array('EN' => 1, 'IT' => 2, 'ES' => 3, 'CHS' => 4));

print_r($strings_ordered);
```

If the arrays are big, it's better to rely on PHP sort algorithms rather than trying to implement custom ones.

Feel free to modify anything in the algorithm (order or whatever).

Comment: the function is almost like I would (see my edit). However, I would prefer that languages are not present in the order, maintain their position. If possible, it would be better if the index was recalculated based on the new positions (0,1,2) and (1,2,4). Thank you very much